# Hibernate - select existence of one-to-many

Tags: hibernate, hql, one-to-many

In hibernate I have entities A and B.  There's is a one-to-many from A to B (A -< B).

I need to write a query where I can select A (plus criteria) plus an additional column that reflects the existence, or not, of any B for each A (with some additional criteria on B)

So there might be one A with no Bs and another A with 2 Bs.  In this case I want 2 rows back, one for each A with "no" for the first and "yes" for the second.  I am not fussed what "no" and "yes" actually are, just so I can distinguish.

If I use a left outer join I will get more than one row per A in the many B case.

How I can I write this in HQL?  Do I perhaps need a group by (but you can't group by entities I think)?

**Additional**: I also need to restrict the Bs that are relevant based on some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `case` clause:

```
select a, case when (a.bs is empty) then false else true end from A a
```

`join` with `group by` can be used as well, but, as you noticed, depending on your DBMS you may need to enumerate all properties of your entity in `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this (was missing the when btw) and it works fine.  However I have an additional problem that the Bs that are relevant for my search need to be restricted so I can't just use the straight collection.  I think I'll just have to do the group by.